# Select last half of list and apply css

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, list

After doing some research I have realised that it is impossible to select the last half of a dynamic list with pure CSS.

I got this from another stack overflow, but I just added the first and last lines for wordpress.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var yourList = $(".supercarousel div");
yourList = yourList.slice(0, Math.floor(yourList.length/2));
});
```

I'm not very good with jQuery and what I would like to do is hide the last half of the list either with display:none or some other method.

For some reason the carousel I'm using duplicates the images but I'm really happy with the carousel other then that.

Comment: post a fiddle or your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector and [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) at this context to accomplish your task,

```
var yourList = $(".supercarousel div");
var len = yourList.length;   
yourList = yourList.filter(':gt('+ ((len/2) - 1) +')');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8mQ53/)

Comment: Thanks so much!! But my markup uses <div> and not <li>. I tried to switch it (see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZZLya/) but it is not working.

Comment: @Jordan Your changes are perfectly alright.. But you forgot to include the Jquery in that fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/ZZLya/1/